# Count on empty list in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When running a `.count` on an empty list in PowerShell the result is empty rather that `0`. In order to work further with the actual amount I've to use an ugly workaround which I'd love to get rid of:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$resultCount = (Get-ADUser  -properties memberof  -filter { ... } | Select Name).count

write-host "count1: $resultCount"

if ($resultCount -lt 1) {
  $resultCount=0
}
write-host ""
write-host "count2: $resultCount"
```

Where the output would be:

```
count1:
count2: 0
```

How can I get rid of the extra condition and still have `0` as the result when the list is empty?

Comment: Can't repro this, but in this case an explicit array often helps, like `@(Get-ADUser ...).Count`

Comment: I can't reproduce this, either; I get `resultCount` of 0 as well.

Comment: @TToni /@Jeff ... maybe that's due to another PowerShell version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if your expression returns one item, you get that item, instead of a list.  The `@()` operator will convert it to a list if it is not already a list:

```
$resultCount = (@(Get-ADUser  -properties memberof  -filter { ... } | Select Name)).count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultCount = ((get-aduser -filter {name -like "*z*"}).Name).count
```

This will return 0 even in the case of empty array. Calling `.Name` on array will create array of names. In modern powershell each variable even if it is not an array have `.count` property and can be addressed `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Measure-Object before you using count method.

```
$resultCount = (Get-ADUser  -properties memberof  -filter { ... } | Select Name| Measure-Object).count
```

Answer (score 0):

Does turning the list into an array help?

```
$resultCount = (Get-ADUser  -properties memberof  -filter { ... } | Select -ExpandProperty Name).Count
```